# how to set new variable to activerecord object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Can I do this in Rails 4?

```
book.new_variable= 4
```

Where book is an ActiveRecord object just fetched from the db.
`new_variable` is not a column in books table.

I was trying to do this but rails gives me error 
undefined method `new_variable=`.

Is there any other way to set variable to ActiveRecord object which is not part of that particular table?

Comment: What do you want to set `new_variable` equal to? What is 4, is it just an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is a virtual attribute. Check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) for some more info.  An ActiveRecord object is still a ruby object, you can use `attr_accessor` to add a variable, with setters/getters.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :new_variable
   ....
end
```